# Can I pass a different model to my grid when using HTML.DisplayFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an application that shows a grid/table of questions and each question has a status dropdown. There are around 1-200 questions and each status drop down has about 50 choices that are the same for every row of the grid.

My controller passes the following model to a view:

```
IEnumerable<Question.Grid>
```

Then in my view I have the following code that prints out the detail lines of a grid table:

```
<tbody class="grid">
@if (Model != null) {
  foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item, "QuestionDetail")
  }
}
</tbody>
```

Each of the grid lines has a status dropdown and I would like to pass the data for the dropdown (same for every row) to the QuestionDetail view. What's the best way for me to send this additional information so that in my view I can have something like the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Question.Status", Status, new { id = "StatusID"})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't pass IENumerable of view models. Rather define one that has IEnumerable as property like this:

```
public class EnumViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Question.Grid> Questions { get; set; }
   public int MyAdditionalFieldIWantedToPassAlong { get; set; }
}
public class Question.Grid
{
  public string MyExistingFields { get; set; }
  // as many as you had
  public string MyAdditionalFields { get; set; }
  // as much as you want
}
```

and have your view receive one model instead of list of models as `@model EnumViewModel`.
At this point it must be very easy for you to add any additional information as your heart pleases inside the EnumViewModel should this information belong there. If its more specific to Questions,put it there and enjoy your items inside every model in the list containing that StatusID.

Think of it as **just a container** for you to hold data your view needs to

1. display and
2. post back to controller

Hope this helps.